# Shared legend in GeoPandas multiplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am creating a multiplot with GeoPandas `GeoDataFrame.plot()` subplots for each month. How can I common legend as well as x and y axis for all subplots and control the figsize?.

I know there is `sharex=True` and `sharey=True` but I do not know where to place it.

`plt.figure(sharex=True, sharey=True)` returns `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sharex'`

`world.plot(column='pop_est', ax=ax, legend=True, sharex=True, sharey=True)` returns `AttributeError: 'PatchCollection' object has no property 'sharex'`

`ax = plt.subplot(4, 3, index + 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)` returns `TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'bool' object`

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

months = pd.DataFrame(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
                      columns = ['months'])

plt.figure()

for index, i in months.iterrows():
    ax = plt.subplot(4, 3, index + 1) # nrows, ncols, axes position
    world.plot(column='pop_est', ax=ax, legend=True)
    ax.set_title(index)
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')

plt.suptitle('This is the figure title', fontsize=12, y=1.05)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `sharex` and `sharey` can be used as arguments to `plt.subplots`, `fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(4,3, sharex=True, sharey=True)`. However this would not create a shared legend.

Comment: It also does not work for me. `ax = plt.subplot(4, 3, index + 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)` yiels `TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'bool' object`.

Comment: Yes, because I said `plt.subplots`

Comment: Thank you for your support. However, replacing `ax = plt.subplot(4, 3, index + 1)` with `fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(4,3, sharex=True, sharey=True)` or `fig, ax_array = plt.subplots(4,3, index + 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)` results in an empty canvas and `TypeError: subplots() got multiple values for argument 'sharex'`, respectively.

Comment: This needs to come outside the loop, and subsequently you would need to loop over the axes inside `ax_array`. But as said, this is just to show where your error comes from, it would not create any shared legends or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Unfortunately, I cannot get it work. I've asked where exactly I've to place code pieces/parameters of which I know they exist and now I have new code pieces/parameters which i have to place somewhere but I do not know where.

Comment: Check e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46069018/4124317

Comment: Or maybe better [the official example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#sharing-axes).

Comment: Or [this one](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/color/color_cycle_default.html).

Comment: Yes, I came across them before. Does not help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The `shared_x` and `share_y` keywords are already explained by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in the comments above. That works fine, I would personally remove all ticks/labels if you are actually showing the entire world. But for subset's it can be helpful.

Creating a shared legend (what Matplotlib would call a colorbar, not a legend) is a bit finicky because Geopandas doesn't returns the axes instead of a mapabble (like Matplotlib usually does). An easy workaround is to get it from the axes collections but this does require some assumptions on which mappable you need if there are multiple.

In this case there is only 1 (patch collection), per axes, and it's identical for each axes. So fetching ith with `axs[0].collections[0]` is straightforward, but not the most robust solution.

An alternative would be to create the `cax` upfront and provide that to Geopandas plot, using the `cax=cax` keyword. But creating the `cax` manually (with fig.add_axes([]), is less convenient.

Using `fig.colorbar` as shown below seems easier since it allows creating the `cax` based on a list/array of axes.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4,3, figsize=(10,7), 
                        facecolor='w',
                        constrained_layout=True, 
                        sharex=True, sharey=True, 
                        subplot_kw=dict(aspect='equal'))

axs = axs.ravel()

fig.suptitle('This is the figure title', fontsize=12, y=1.05)

for index, i in months.iterrows():

    axs[index].set_title(index)
    world.plot(column='pop_est', ax=axs[index])


# assume it's the first (and only) mappable
patch_col = axs[0].collections[0]
cb = fig.colorbar(patch_col, ax=axs, shrink=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, fantastic :) I wasn't able to get ImportanceOfBeingErnest's code pieces running.